# How do I Object.assign to sub-property of an object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

At 1st I create an object `principalLegal`, then I add to it's `address#` properties all of the properties of `address` constant.
I do this because I don't want to manually declare many times over all the `address` properties inside of `principalLegal.address#`.

```
const address = {
  index: {
    id: "index",
    text: "Index",
  },
  country: {
    id: "country",
    text: "Country",
  },
  // Many other fields here
};

const principalLegal = {
  _id: "principalLegalData",
  text: "Principal Data"
  name: {
    id: "principalName",
    text: "Principal name"
  },
  address1: {
    _id: "principalAddress1",
    text: "Principal Address 1"
  },
  address2: {
    _id: "principalAddress2",
    text: "Principal Address 2"
  },
  // address3 and so on..

}

Object.assign(principalLegal.address1, address);
Object.assign(principalLegal.address2, address);
```

But, when I try to access `principalLegal.address1.country`, Typescript says
`Property 'country' does not exist on type '{ _id: string; _text: string; }'.`
Which means that Typescript ignores all the `Object.assign` operations.

What is the way to make this right, without repeating `address` properties many times over and over inside of `principalLegal`?

Comment: Have you tried using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)?

Comment: `principalLegal.address1 = {...principalLegal.address1, ...address};` instead of `Object.assign`? Gives the same error :(

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript doesn't allow a variable's type to change arbitrarily... so if you were removing properties or changing a property type from one type to another, the only way to deal with this would be to use a new variable for each mutation.  This is a viable (but not the only) option for adding (or refining) properties too, so here's one way you'd do it:

```
function modifyProperty<T, K extends keyof T, U>(
  obj: T,
  key: K,
  modify: (oldValue: T[K]) => U
) {
  let ret = obj as any;
  ret[key] = modify(obj[key]);
  return ret as { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? U : T[P] };
}
```

The function `modifyProperty(obj, key, modify)` takes an object `obj` and one of its keys `key`, and a `modify` callback that converts the old value to the new value.  Here's how one might use it:

```
const principalLegal1 = modifyProperty(principalLegal, "address1", a =>
  Object.assign(a, address)
);
principalLegal1.address1.country; // okay

const principalLegal2 = modifyProperty(principalLegal1, "address2", a =>
  Object.assign(a, address)
);
principalLegal2.address1.country; // okay
principalLegal2.address2.country; // okay
```

Notice how after each mutation with `modifyProperty` you throw away your existing `principalLegal` variable and use the returned value instead.  This is possibly clunky, but it is consistent with a static type system in which the type of a variable cannot change.

---

Now luckily for you, you are not changing the type of `principalLegal` *arbitrarily*... instead you are *narrowing* it by adding subproperties.  And TypeScript does have the ability to use [control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#control-flow-based-type-analysis) to narrow the types of variables.

Unfortunately there's currently no built-in way in TypeScript for a function call to just narrow the type of one of its arguments (although this is slated to change in TS3.7 with the [`asserts` type predicate modifier](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695)).  So there's no direct way to say that `Object.assign(foo, bar)` will narrow `foo` itself.

---

## UPDATE

The `asserts` modifier just got merged to master so the nightly builds support it now.  If you install `typescript@next` locally, you can do something like this and see that it works:

```
function assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): asserts target is T & U {
  Object.assign(target, source);
}

assign(principalLegal.address1, address);
principalLegal.address1.country; // okay

assign(principalLegal.address2, address);
principalLegal.address1.country; // okay
principalLegal.address2.country; // okay
```

---

For now, you can use a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) that does the assignment and returns `true`.  When you then check the return value and `throw` if it is not `true`, the compiler will understand that the type of the variable has been unconditionally narrowed.  It's a bit of an abuse of type guards, and the `asserts` modifier should hopefully fix this soon.

Here's the function:

```
function assign<T, U>(x: T, y: U): x is T & U {
  Object.assign(x, y);
  return true;
}
```

And here's how we'd use it:

```
if (!assign(principalLegal.address1, address)) throw new Error();
principalLegal.address1.country; // okay

if (!assign(principalLegal.address2, address)) throw new Error();
principalLegal.address1.country; // okay
principalLegal.address2.country; // okay
```

This is a bit annoying but probably less annoying than discarding variables; it's up to you, I guess.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//?ts=Nightly#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwQJwKYQjAvDA3gKBhgEswFUAPALj0KJIRoCJTyKmAaOoqSqZgJJlKTOgF8uRUAFcwUZAE8aBeg2Yy5iztxi8K-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-XT3qzwJSphEk6vKVwYN0ADyZtQrJpcAwxByYH1cEPYIwAbD0Q31Vyc6vz7ONI05iRDAdhuEqcAKOO4CTh+WRfoE4ILg6-LIIKwr5jBW6nDue4YMih7HkQZ6mheUBXjed4Pk+-wQK+AbvnCm5weCP7Uac-6mJoqbAfYIBgRBGFMSxiLMQBihASBvHgTETIsmyHLXhAt5gBKUp6vq1CalKNragGNAUCQmDijAABkA4RkRJFkYpFEUFpdF0OWla6MgnrRNY+C8jA+oAIQKUp64MZ+tRCfuVGIgGQaeChADuwyoLFACiyAocg+r2QJwU4X+olcRJfExJ5Pl+RRGUZCFuFhScEW6B4MVxYlyUgKl6WBbBmW-mxOXiTx+WlYE5VIuxZhidxoHgUAA)